# How to write unittest for variable assignment in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest

This is in `Python 2.7`.  I have a class called `class A`, and there are some attributes that I want to throw an exception when being set by the user:

```
myA = A()
myA.myattribute = 9   # this should throw an error
```

I want to write a `unittest` that ensures that this throws an error.

After creating a test class and inheriting `unittest.TestCase`, I tried to write a test like this:

```
myA = A()
self.assertRaises(AttributeError, eval('myA.myattribute = 9'))
```

But, this throws a `syntax error`.  However, if I try `eval('myA.myattribute = 9')`, it throws the attribute error, as it should.

How do I write a unittest to test this correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `assertRaises` as a context manager:

```
with self.assertRaises(AttributeError):
    myA.myattribute = 9
```

The [documentation shows more examples for this if you are interested](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example). The documentation for [assertRaises](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) has a lot more detail on this subject as well.

From that documentation:

> If only the exception and possibly the msg arguments are given, return a context manager so that the code under test can be written
>   inline rather than as a function:
>
> ```
> with self.assertRaises(SomeException):
>      do_something()
> ```

which is exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

`self.assertRaises` takes a callable (and optionally one or more arguments for that callable) as its argument; you are providing the value that results from calling the callable with its arguments. The correct test would be <strike>`self.assertRaises(AttributeError, eval, 'myA.myattribute = 9')`</strike>

```
# Thanks to @mgilson for something that actually works while
# resembling the original attempt.
self.assertRaises(AttributeError, eval, 'myA.myattribute = 9', locals())
```

However, you should use `assertRaises` as a context manager, which allows you to write the much more natural

```
with self.assertRaises(AttributeError):
    myA.myattribute = 9
```

Comment: Would that first form work?  `eval` will evaluate the expression in the current namespace -- which is the namespace in which `eval` is getting called which would _not_ have `myA` defined.  If you're going to use the functional form (which isn't advised), you probably should go with `self.assertRaises(AttributeError, setattr, myA, 'myattribute', 9)`, _or_ you'll have to pass the current function's locals through:  `self.assertRaises(AttributeError, eval, 'myA.myattribute = 9', locals())`

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really give any thought to how you would correctly use `eval`. I should have just explained that `assertRaises` takes something that *it* can call, rather than the result of a expression, and left it at that.